# Vertices not connected on duplicate?

Tags: vertices, faces

Complete blender noob here.

In the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmDeKk4VEHk

you can see that everytime they duplicate the vertices it automatically connects them instead of having to select them both and pressing F. How can I enable this because this doesn't happen for me.

Hopefully someone knows the answer, thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, he doesn't duplicate, he extrudes –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Moonboots wrote in the comments, you can extrude a vertex/vertices with E

[image]